# Should I divide my table into multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

I have a table that's called `questions` This table portrays a poll. It contains 12 columns: `id, title,`type`, choice1, choice2, img1, img2, upvotes, downvotes, comments, shares, date_stamp`

I'm having difficulty of whether or not keeping the table the way it is or splitting it into two based on similar attributes. For example, there could be a table named `questions`that contains columns: `id, title, type, choice1, choice2, img1, img2, date_stamp`and another table called `question_props` that contains columns: `id, upvotes, downvotes, comments, shares`

All of the table columns will be used and the SQL statement that will be used the most will be `SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 10` assuming the tables are combined into one.

Based on this information, would it be better to split the table into two or leave it be as one table?

Comment: What is the motivation for splitting? If the relationship between them is 1:1 (which your question implies), then this seems like premature optimisation to me. Is there a query pattern you expect to be faster when split? Some write concurrency issue? Surely partitioning would make more sense for you than splitting?

Comment: @AndySavage Could you give me an example of partitioning?

Answer (score 0):

Premature optimization.

If you get to the point where you are getting hundreds of up/down votes per *second*, *then* you should split the table in two, putting the rapidly updated counters in a separate table.

`PARTITION`, I believe, would not help at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I put only the counters (Upvotes, downvotes, shares, comments) in a separate table? Also, how will that increase performance compared to just putting them all in one table?

Comment: It somewhat reduces contention between the rapid-fire updating of counters and the rest of the activity.